# Error in Apache Virtual Host

Tags: apache

I'm trying to create an Apache Virtual Host and I get the follow error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

My host.txt is:

```
127.0.0.1 slimapp
```

And my httpd-vhost.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName slimapp
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/slimapp/public/"
</VirtualHost>
```

My httpd.conf is:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: After you changed all your settings .. Did you restart your web server?

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache.

Comment: Which version of Apache?  Older versions required you to put NameVirtualHost directive for this to work.  Recent versions do ont.  Just a thought.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.4.23 This is an old one?

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a Chrome error no? Ping slimapp to see if it even resolves to 127.0.0.1

Comment: No. Doesn't work in any browser.

Comment: Did you read in any documentation that having `host.txt` file will help in name resolution?

Comment: Documentation no. Every tutorial I see say so. Do you mean it doesn't?

Comment: Usually not, for Linux the file is `/etc/hosts/`, for Windows it is `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: It was in this file that I inserted 127.0.0.1 slamapp

Comment: Did you try `ping slamapp` from `cmd`?  Conversely does `127.0.0.1` resolve?

Comment: I tried now ping slimapp: The ping request could not find the slamapp host. Check the name and try again. That mean host.txt is wrong ?